# Finding PaaS Provider and uploading a software

Tags: c#, sql, paas

I have designed Windows form application (using C# .net framework) and now wants to upload to the cloud using PaaS provider for demonstration.

I need help  in regards to finding a PaaS provider (I am unsure about this I have never done this) and also need to know how to upload my application to Cloud? Also my application is connected to local database how would that work in cloud? Do I upload the database as well?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

MS Azure could be a possible platform. I haven't worked with Azure to tell something about that rather I know about app engine. Azure documentation - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/.